# Sending data to web using arduino GSM module using GPRS

Tags: web, arduino, gsm

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GSM(9, 10); // RX, TX
int sensor=5;

enum _parseState {
PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE,

PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO,

PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE,
PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT,
PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH,

PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH,
PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT
};

byte parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
char buffer[80];
 byte pos = 0;

 int contentLength = 0;

 void resetBuffer() {
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  pos = 0;
 }

  void sendGSM(const char* msg, int waitMs = 500) {
  GSM.println(msg);
 delay(waitMs);
 while(GSM.available()) {
  parseATText(GSM.read());
   }
   }

 void setup()
 {
   GSM.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"zongwap\"");  
 sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=1,1",300);
sendGSM("AT+HTTPINIT");  
sendGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
sendGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://afridiofkh.000webhostapp.com?
sensor1="" + sensor + ""\"""");
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPACTION=0"); 
  }

void loop()
   {  
   while(GSM.available()) {
    parseATText(GSM.read());
    }
   }

  void parseATText(byte b) {

 buffer[pos++] = b;

    if ( pos >= sizeof(buffer) )
    resetBuffer(); // just to be safe

   /*
  // Detailed debugging
    Serial.println();
   Serial.print("state = ");
   Serial.println(state);
   Serial.print("b = ");
   Serial.println(b);
  Serial.print("pos = ");
  Serial.println(pos);
  Serial.print("buffer = ");
  Serial.println(buffer);*/

  switch (parseState) {
  case PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE: 
    {
  if ( b == '\n' )
    resetBuffer();
  else {        
    if ( pos == 3 && strcmp(buffer, "AT+") == 0 ) {
      parseState = PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO;
    }
    else if ( b == ':' ) {
      //Serial.print("Checking message type: ");
      //Serial.println(buffer);

      if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPACTION:") == 0 ) {
        Serial.println("Received HTTPACTION");
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE;
      }
      else if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPREAD:") == 0 ) {
        Serial.println("Received HTTPREAD");            
        parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH;
      }
      resetBuffer();
    }
  }
}
break;

   case PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO:
     {
     if ( b == '\n' ) {
    Serial.print("Ignoring echo: ");
    Serial.println(buffer);
    parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE:
   {
  if ( b == ',' ) {
    Serial.print("HTTPACTION type is ");
    Serial.println(buffer);
    parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

 case PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT:
   {
  if ( b == ',' ) {
    Serial.print("HTTPACTION result is ");
    Serial.println(buffer);
    parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH:
  {
  if ( b == '\n' ) {
    Serial.print("HTTPACTION length is ");
    Serial.println(buffer);

    // now request content
    GSM.print("AT+HTTPREAD=0,");
    GSM.println(buffer);

    parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH:
    {
  if ( b == '\n' ) {
    contentLength = atoi(buffer);
    Serial.print("HTTPREAD length is ");
    Serial.println(contentLength);

    Serial.print("HTTPREAD content: ");

    parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

   case PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT:
    {
  // for this demo I'm just showing the content bytes in the serial monitor
  Serial.write(b);

  contentLength--;

  if ( contentLength <= 0 ) {

    // all content bytes have now been read

    parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;
 }
}
```

i even don't understand the code but i get the idea and when i am trying to post the data to web its not working i don't know what's wrong with it
i am getting web content back but i can't post data to the web 
i tried both get and post method non of them brought luck to me

Comment: I used the same code and it worked.I just wanted same output as you need.can you explain me which url of webhost you using in the above code

Comment: Your http request has got few mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http request you made in your code has some mistakes.You can't request from arduino as you did.

When using 000webhost for database the best way is to make use of PHP.You can upload PHP files by selecting File Manager [image] and then select "Upload files now" .In that there is a folder named "public_html" ,it's where the PHP codes are to be uploaded.

Now here is what you want to do.You want to create a PHP code which would perform the insertion operation to the database when the URL of this php code is requested.Then you can request this link from arduino for performing insertion.

The PHP code is ( Please provide your username,password,dbname,table name,column name in the provided locations of the code and upload it as i said above)  :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "provide your username here";
$password = "password here";
$dbname = "database name here";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['sensor1'])."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Obtain the URL of the uploaded PHP code (right click uploaded file and click view , then copy URL in the browser). You can use it in your Arduino sketch.

Your arduino code should look like ( URL in this sketch is incomplete replace it with one obtained as i said above [ `http://afridiofkh.000webhostapp.com/phpfilename.php` this is the one to be replaced.starting from http till ? mark is to be replaced] ) :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GSM(9, 10); // RX, TX
int sensor=5;

enum _parseState {
PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE,

PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO,

PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE,
PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT,
PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH,

PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH,
PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT
};

byte parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
char buffer[130],url[130]; //adjust as your url length
 byte pos = 0;

 int contentLength = 0;

 void resetBuffer() {
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  pos = 0;
 }

  void sendGSM(const char* msg, int waitMs = 500) {
  GSM.println(msg);
 delay(waitMs);
 while(GSM.available()) {
  parseATText(GSM.read());
   }
   }

 void setup()
 {
   GSM.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"zongwap\"");  
 sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=1,1",300);
sendGSM("AT+HTTPINIT");  
sendGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://afridiofkh.000webhostapp.com/phpfilename.php?sensor1=%d\"",sensor);
  sendGSM(url);
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPACTION=0"); 
  }

void loop()
   {  
   while(GSM.available()) {
    parseATText(GSM.read());
    }
   }

  void parseATText(byte b) {

 buffer[pos++] = b;

    if ( pos >= sizeof(buffer) )
    resetBuffer(); // just to be safe

   /*
  // Detailed debugging
    Serial.println();
   Serial.print("state = ");
   Serial.println(state);
   Serial.print("b = ");
   Serial.println(b);
  Serial.print("pos = ");
  Serial.println(pos);
  Serial.print("buffer = ");
  Serial.println(buffer);*/

  switch (parseState) {
  case PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE: 
    {
  if ( b == '\n' )
    resetBuffer();
  else {        
    if ( pos == 3 && strcmp(buffer, "AT+") == 0 ) {
      parseState = PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO;
    }
    else if ( b == ':' ) {
      //Serial.print("Checking message type: ");
      //Serial.println(buffer);

      if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPACTION:") == 0 ) {
        Serial.println("Received HTTPACTION");
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE;
      }
      else if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPREAD:") == 0 ) {
        Serial.println("Received HTTPREAD");            
        parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH;
      }
      resetBuffer();
    }
  }
}
break;

   case PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO:
     {
     if ( b == '\n' ) {
    Serial.print("Ignoring echo: ");
    Serial.println(buffer);
    parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE:
   {
  if ( b == ',' ) {
    Serial.print("HTTPACTION type is ");
    Serial.println(buffer);
    parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

 case PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT:
   {
  if ( b == ',' ) {
    Serial.print("HTTPACTION result is ");
    Serial.println(buffer);
    parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH:
  {
  if ( b == '\n' ) {
    Serial.print("HTTPACTION length is ");
    Serial.println(buffer);

    // now request content
    GSM.print("AT+HTTPREAD=0,");
    GSM.println(buffer);

    parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH:
    {
  if ( b == '\n' ) {
    contentLength = atoi(buffer);
    Serial.print("HTTPREAD length is ");
    Serial.println(contentLength);

    Serial.print("HTTPREAD content: ");

    parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;

   case PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT:
    {
  // for this demo I'm just showing the content bytes in the serial monitor
  Serial.write(b);

  contentLength--;

  if ( contentLength <= 0 ) {

    // all content bytes have now been read

    parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
    resetBuffer();
  }
}
break;
 }
}
```

This would perform the insertion operation as you need to.PHP is easy as it can be used to extend the operations.

Comment: Try this . Tell me if it works or if you face any problem.

Comment: i'll try this one tonight when i get free thanks for your response

Comment: yes it does work for me but i wasn't stuck at that problem i did already what he said the solution was some how different and it worked for me i found the solution by myself

Comment: i will post the exact solution the upper one is also a solution i mean you have to start from there but then the problem i face wasn't this one i already did the stuff what he said