# How to get start with internet of things and easy way to monitor my values in internet .?

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspbian, iot

I am new to IoT (Internet of Things). I have watched a few videos but 
I have a few problems here. The thing is, here my work as so far:

1. A controller (Arduino or Pi etc..) connected with devices like sensors
2. I receive the output from sensors and I store it in MySQL (local).

How to send my sensor data to the web with the help of internet (ex. How to  monitor or send temp value in a website or anything)?

- How can I send sensor values to my web page where I can monitor?
- To monitor my values do I need to buy or own a website?

Comment: Pay some respect to the responses you receive. Accept and upvote if you found the content useful. Else please provide a comment on it. This is how stack works. It took much time to prepare a content, so we must respect it.

Comment: I apology for that . I need little information regarding explanation , that will ask in comment section..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need is :

1. Send your data to a server (Thus it can be used in future; Here after tell that you are trying to store to a database, as you did locally).
2. How can you view what you stored.

> Send your data to a server

You can acheive this by using a **GSM module** (remeber it should support http services) - I would suggest GSM SIM 900A (as you can find plenty of online tutorials on it) - and You need to get a **server**, better online (useful for viewing what you stored too). Don't worry about cost, there are some websites which provide you free hosting (You can go for payed one as well if you need).

Eg : [000webhost](https://in.000webhost.com/)

Prepare database as your need.So now you got your sever and database ready, arduino ready.

Now how you can store data to database from arduino , luckily I already answered about it on stack - [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243516/7699452).

WOW we completed phase one!!

> How can you view what you stored

Its got plenty of options :

- Visit database : You can just go to the database and find what you got in it, But I wont suggest that because - It not so user interactive (but if no other option works you can go for it - usually never happens)
- website : I would suggest this option. It is not laborious task to create a web page and connect it to server. As you already own a server, you can use same server for hosting website.
- Mobile App : Another option is to create a mobile app and connect it to database, so that you can view the contents on your mobile. It is not easy unless you are good in android.

So we are done. Think this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
And sorry i took long time to reply yours answer.
Here i want to know that , i knw about the ooowebhost which you have mentioned , but the problem where im getting was , im not able to send my sensor data from my controller to the web host automatically (i have tried few tutorials but didn't get it ,all i have tried was filezilla(becoz i prefer python program only, rest of languages were complex interms of IoT(for me)))
Can you please suggest anything regarding sending sensor values (it would be great )

Comment: have you wrote codes for requesting web pages ? If yes did that worked succesfully and what kind of connectivity you using, like wifi, gsm,ethernet etc.

Comment: 1.Here i have tried raspberry pi 2 model b , so i can directly plug in wifi module so that i can use internet connectivity .

Comment: 2. No , i didn't write any codes for connectivity.

Comment: If you want to send data to webhost you should do that. You should establish a connection to the network and you can pass your sensor data on the url. This is hoe it is to be done

Comment: as it is a raspberry pi it is easy. Just dont look the arduino part in the link i provided in the above answer and you can create a php document with the database insertion action specified in that document and this url is to be requested from the pi. And pass the sensor data on this link to the PHP document. You can use any webhosting

Comment: Thank you for the response . And i will look into the document amd learn.

Comment: One thing i want to ask , do i need any filezilla and wamp kind of thing

Comment: yes you have to use either filezilla or should use another webhosts.

Comment: Yeah i try what you have said , Thank you for your 
For your information

Comment: Yeah , jus now i came to know that .